# Loading table sections when using headers

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I cant seem to wrap my head around this. I have googled, and overstacked for hours now looking for examples that i can relate to. What I have is two arrays.

The name of my first NSMutableArray is "showDates".

```
I have 3 objects in here.
Object 0: "Today, May 20th"
Object 1: "Tomorrow, May 21st"
Object 2: "Saturday, May 22nd"
```

Then I have my second NSMutableArray named "showTimes"
I have about 15 objects in there with strings in each object. ( i hope that makes sense? )
Each object is structured like this:

```
       Object 0:
          showID @"98022"
          eventID @"833"
          showTime @"1:30pm"
          showDate @"Today, May 20th"
          auditorium @"9"
          venue @"2991"

       Object 1:
          showID @"98222"
          eventID @"813"
          showTime @"2:30pm"
          showDate @"Tomorrow, May 21st"
          auditorium @"9"
          venue @"2991"

Etc, etc, ....
```

I have the headers working great in my tableView, but I cant seem to figure out how to add the objects in my "showTimes" array under the correct header. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Details

First, you need to implement the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method in your TableView's data source.
This method takes the row of an NSIndexPath (which is an integer) as an argument. NSIndexPath, when used in TableViews, has the properties `section` and `row`. All you need to do is get the value of the `section` property and return the number of rows you'd like to appear in that section. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   switch(section)
   {
      //This would represent your first section, "Today..."
      case 0: //implement logic to find how many data objects need to be represented as rows for this section
         break;
      //second section, "Tomorrow"
      case 1: //logic
         break;
      //third section
      case 2:  //logic
         break;
   }
}
```

Now that you've accomplished that, it's time to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Unlike the previous method, this one takes a whole NSIndexPath as an argument, usually called `indexPath` in the docs. Simply find the section of the path using the property accessor `indexPath.section`, and the row within the section with `indexPath.row`.

### Important Note

Having said that, all this might be a bit easier if you rearrange the information currently contained in the ShowTimes array. If the array isn't sorted, then (for example) the logic in each case I showed for `numberOfRowsInSection:` will require you to traverse the entire array and test each element to see if it belongs in the table section being requested. I would recommend splitting the ShowTimes array into three separate arrays (one for each section) before the table is displayed, so that all you need is a simple `count` call to the appropriate array in each case. The implementation for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` would be simplified as well.

### Summary

Think of it this way. Methods like `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` decide the layout of rows in your table *long before* a single cell is even loaded - before your data is even considered. As each cell is about to be displayed, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` decides what that cell will contain based on the NSIndexPath of the cell, or more specifically, based on the `section` and `row` properties of that IndexPath.
In short, the only thing linking a cell to its content is the IndexPath, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` decides how the link is made.

For further reading, take a look at this page from the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5). Specifically, the section entitled "Populating the Table View With Data".

Comment: excellent suggestions. It took me forever to get it right, but when i read your suggestion i knew that was the answer. My tableview is now bad ass! Thanks to Mike Crandall who helped me implement the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

In your table view's dataSource class, you need to implement the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to provide the cell for each row in the table. Using

`[indexPath section]`

where indexPath is the second parameter passed into the method, you can determine which section the cell that was requested belongs to (you need to also implement numberOfRowsInSection: to inform the table view of how many cells it should request in each section). Hope that helps.

Comment: this did indeed work, but i had a little more of a complex situation than i described above. thanks for the post!